# How should I update ID field values for all records based on previous values?

Tags: mysql, update

I need a SQL query that can update ID fields for all records in a table from their previous values to a new value based on that previous value.

For example, if the ID is 1, I want to change it to 9991 - prepending '999' to every ID in the table.

What is the most efficient means of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple options come to mind.  If you have a charish data type:

```
update table set column=concat('999',column);
```

If you have an integer type find the max value, let's say it's under 10,000 then

```
update table set column=9990000+column
```

Comment: Thanks, the second suggestion worked well for the id field (which is a bigint(20) in my case).  I'm glad you pointed out to find the max value first.  I needed to update these columns in this way because I will be importing them into another duplicate table (duplicate structure; not duplicate records) and did not want the import to fail because of duplicate records.

Comment: If the tables in on the same server you could just run insert into newtable (col2, col3, .. colN) select col2, col3, colN from oldtable;  Where you leave out your id field in bot the values list and the select list.  This assumes your id column is an auto_increment field.  Then you just let mysql assign new ids to the rows in the new table

Comment: @atxdba: But ths (your comment) way will not take care of any referencing columns in other tables. While your Update will (as long as there is an `ON UPDATE CASCADE`).

Comment: I agree with ypercube's comment.

Comment: Yes, in my case, another table was referencing these values.  I had to perform the same update procedure on that table as well.